# How to make this format of array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to make an array in PHP but it should be in specific format such this:

```
array(1, 5, 3)
```

I mean, I have the values 1, 5 and 3 from my database, so I had to loop it with the use of array_push

```
$a=array();

foreach( $db_nums as $db_num ){
array_push($a, $db_num);
}

print_r($a);
```

but it outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 5 [2] => 3 );
```

i want it to be only:

```
array(1, 5, 3 );
```

Any ideas how? Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: I don't really understand your question? How do you mean `in a specific format`.

Comment: You're maybe looking for var_export? (http://php.net/var_export)  Otherwise, no idea.

Comment: did you mean that the elements should be in ascending order?

Comment: all you need is $myarray = array(1,2,3) and you done with php

Comment: i appreciate your reply guys, i updated the question....

Comment: so you actually just want to echo values? as all arrays are key=>value pairs. echo implode(' ',$array);

Comment: @Dagon, no i still want it to be array..

Comment: you cant have an array with out keys. "An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys." you never have to do anything with the keys, but they have to still exist.

Comment: may i ask what will be the equivalent of array(1, 5, 3 ); without keys?

Comment: its not an array if there are no keys. array(1, 5, 3 ); is the same as Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 5 [2] => 3 ); if you don't specify the keys php does it for you starting at 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the below code:

```
$Array = array(1,2,3);
```

Edit:

```
$a = array();

foreach( $db_nums as $db_num )
{
    $a[] = $db_num;
}

print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  $array = array("foo", "bar", "hallo", "world");  var_dump($array); ?>
```

You can use that

Answer (score 0):

```
$db_nums = array(1, 2, 3); //pointless example, but comes from DB
$a = array();
foreach ($db_nums as $n) {
    $a[] = $n;
}
var_export($a);
```

That will output:

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 3,
)
```

Which is about as close as you're going to get without writing your own function to do it.

(Also note that in this example, you could just directly do var_export($db_nums).)